# "is not JSON serializable" error on Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4

OK, I know it sounds like very basic and duplicated question, but I can't find anything specifically about python 3.4 on this matter.

I'm running into this problem since some hours and I can't find a solution. I have the exact same code running on a python 3.0 script without problems, this one is running on python 3.4.

It is a Django application. In a view, eventually I reach to this following line:

```
urls = URL.objects.all()
return HttpResponse(status=http.client.OK, 
    content=serializers.serialize('json', urls), 
    content_type='application/json')
```

URL is defined as:

```
class URL(models.Model):
    # fields...

    def to_JSON(self):
        def _try(o):
            try:
                return o.__dict__
            except:
                return str(o)

        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: _try(o), sort_keys=True, indent=0, separators=(',',':')).replace('\n', '')
```

The class contains a `to_JSON` method which should be called when Django's `serializers.serialize` converts every single object of the collection into JSON. This method has always worked for me since python 2.4 to 3.0, but on 3.4 it seems that any JSON package checks for the existence of `to_JSON` method anymore. Is this right? How should I be doing it now?

Comment: Could you test the code in 3.1, 3.2, 3.3? Maybe if you find the first subversion that fails you be able to tell the problem by looking at the release announcement / changelog.

Comment: @Kay that will take some time but for the sake of research, I'll do that and post back here the results